# Run webpack with HMR client on another system

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-hmr

I have a working webpack setup with hot module reload, that works great as long as I keep everything on local host.

But I'd like to have another computer running the client that also has hot module reload enabled.

Unfortunately when I try to do this, the client just complains that it can't connect to the hot module reload server on "http://localhost:3001/sockjs-node/info".

If I change my webpack config file to have "webpack-dev-server/client?http://(ip address):4000", and change my webpack server.js to run on port 4000, the client still gives the error that it can't connect to "http://localhost:3001/sockjs-node/info", even though it is loading the page perfectly fine.

Obviously I'm missing some config setting to tell webpack-dev-server to insert a different client address for hot module reload, but I can't find it.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You said any help ... I've implemented that on one of my projects, it's documented : https://github.com/topheman/d3-react-experiments this is the `NO_LOCALHOST=true` env var to add. Code is self explaining, it would be double work to do it there.

Comment: @topheman alright, I'll take a look. Thanks!